# What does really mean by the picture below?

Tags: vector-analysis

[image] I wanna know the what that value represents mathematically or physically?

Comment: If you rearrange that last equality, you have $\frac{\vec{A}}{|\vec{A}|} \cdot \frac{\vec{B}}{|\vec{B}|} = \cos \theta$, which shows that (after normalizing down to unit vectors) the dot product measures is the cosine of the angle between the two vectors.

Comment: It doesn't directly answer your question, but you might like [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LyGKycYT2v0) which gives you one way to think about dot-products.